# How to Avoid continuous triggering of HTML5 DeviceOrientationEvent

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to tilt an image based on HTML5 DeviceOrientation event. However, I am seeing that the event is getting continuously fired even when the device is stable i.e non rotating/non moving. In the following code snippet, the console log is printed continuously. What is the possible reason, how can I stop it.

I tried both capturing and bubbling,

```
  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
              window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
              var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
              console.log("tiltLR..........",tiltLR);
              }, false);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent needed to use this type of event listener before so I am not familiar with the output.

However, I believe you would need to compare the old tilt with the new tilt. If the new tilt is substantially greater or less then... execute code.

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {

       var originalTilt = undefined,
           tolerance = 5;

       window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {

          if (eventData.gamma > originalTilt + tolerance ||
              eventData.gamma < originalTilt - tolerance){
              var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
              console.log("tiltLR..........",tiltLR);
              originalTilt = tiltLR;
          }

       }, false);
  }
```